# How to get a input field value which is located in a table td

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to receive the value from an `input` field, which is located in an table `td`? The click button console.log `temp` which again contains the `innerText` of each table td. I am struggling to address the second cell for each row, where I want to receive the value from the input field.

What would be best practice?

```js
 var data = [
            {
                "name": "Paul",
                "birthday": "01.01.2000"
            },
            {
                "name": "Lisa",
                "birthday": "04.04.1998"
            },
            {
                "name": "Kyle",
                "birthday": "08.08.1990"
            },
            {
                "name": "Cindy",
                "birthday": "12.12.2002"
            }
        ]

        var table = document.getElementById("table")

        createTable()

        function createTable() {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                tableDateRow = `<tr id="row${i}">
                    <td>${data[i].name}</td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="datepicker" value="${data[i].birthday}"></td>
                    </tr>`
                table.innerHTML += tableDateRow
            }
        }

        $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
        })

        var button = document.getElementById("click")

        button.addEventListener("click", function () {
            const temp = []

            $("table tr").each(function () {
                var rowDataObject = new Object;
                var actualData = $(this).find('td');
                if (actualData.length > 0) {
                    rowDataObject.name = actualData[0].innerText;
                    rowDataObject.birthday = actualData[1].innerText;
                    // get input field value and store in rowDataobject.birthday
                    temp.push(rowDataObject)
                }
            })
            console.log(temp)
        })
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="table">
        <tbody>
            <!-- filled by script -->
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button id="click">Click</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can use jQuery's `find()` method to retrieve all the `tr` within the `table`. From there you can use `map()` to create an array of objects containing the values.

Also note that your current code uses a mix of plain JS and jQuery. If you're already including jQuery in the page then you may as well use it. As such you can simplify the code quite a lot, and also make it more robust by passing references to the functions instead of relying on variable declared at a higher scope.

Try this:

```js
var data = [{ "name": "Paul", "birthday": "01.01.2000" }, { "name": "Lisa", "birthday": "04.04.1998" }, { "name": "Kyle", "birthday": "08.08.1990" }, { "name": "Cindy", "birthday": "12.12.2002" }]
var $table = $("#table");
var $button = $("#click");

createTable($table)

function createTable($t) {
  let html = data.map(row => `<tr><td>${row.name}</td><td><input type="text" class="datepicker" value="${row.birthday}"></td></tr>`);
  $t.append(html);
}

$(".datepicker").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
  showOtherMonths: true,
  selectOtherMonths: true,
})

$button.on("click", e => {
  let temp = $table.find('tbody tr').map((i, el) => ({
    name: el.querySelector('td:nth-child(1)').innerText,
    birthday: el.querySelector('input').value.trim()
  })).get();
  console.log(temp)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <!-- filled by script -->
  </tbody>
</table>

<button id="click" type="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. JQuery is new for me, I will adapt your hints. Your console.log does not include the names anymore. Could you kindly explain why you neet to trim the value in your button.on("click"..) approach?

Comment: Sorry - I missed that you returned an object with both values. I've updated the answer for you

Comment: Although, it's worth noting that the object created from the table would be identical to the one you used to build the table in the first instance. Could you not just store the `data` somewhere within scope and re-use it as needed?

Comment: This is only a snippet. My main app loads external data to populate a table, users then  can modify the table data and it will be stored. I was struggling with the input field where you helped me.